# Java - How do I stop my program to read next line(s) after an "Exception"

Tags: java

I need some help.

When I made a "catch Exception" thing, it wont stop reading more lines.
How do I prevent this?

I did like this:

```
try {
    double1 = Double.parseDouble(args[2]);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    user.sendMessage("Can't parse 3rd argument into a number!");
} 
if(double1 > 200 || double1 <= 0) {
user.sendMessage("Error. Nothing special here.");
}
```

When I get an exception for parsing error, it will continue reading to read the other error prevention method [ if (double > 200 || double 1 <= 0) {} ] and because double1 wasn't a number, it will send out to the user who perform the action another ERROR string.

This is how it looks for the user:

Message: Can't parse 3rd argument into a number!

Message: Error. Nothing special here.

Two error messages, one isn't even supposed to be there. How do I make it so only the first error shows up? So it prevents the 2nd error message?

Comment: How are you handling the exception? You're just printing the stack, sending a message - but continuing on with the code. You should either throw the exception after handling it, or return from the function.

Comment: Don't catch the Exception and pretend it didn't happen.  Only catch it when there isn't any code after it you wouldn't want running after an Exception occurred.

Answer (score 6):

```
try {
    double1 = Double.parseDouble(args[2]);

    if (double1 > 200 || double1 <= 0) {
        user.sendMessage("Error. Nothing special here.");
    }
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    user.sendMessage("Can't parse 3rd argument into a number!");
}
```

This works, but it is not a very good design. The `NumberFormatException` is not properly handled, since you are logging it and then allowing the rest of the code to run. You actually want it to stop the execution and not run the rest of the code (the `if` condition), so that's what the exception should do - either do an early return or propagate the exception to be handled further up in the stack.

Comment: It works fine, I just tested it with a hardcoded double (1.1, "test" and 201 for the respective scenarios) and System.out.println instead of user.sendMessage.

Comment: Eclipsum - if this doesn't work, then you have not >>understood<< the answer.  The real point here is that you need to understand what your (original) code is actually doing ... and then figure out where you need to put that test for "nothing special" to meet your requirements.  (I take it that this is homework or an exercise or something like that, and the aim is that you are trying to learn how to program in Java.)

Comment: The problem is this program/plugin that runs by another program, which doesn't support this method, in some way.